# Linq OrderByDescending not working

Tags: linq, group-by

I'm doing queries like these:

With Join

```
public IEnumerable<ProblemsViewModel_Base> GetProblemsSearchClassification(string searchTerm)
    {
        var subjectProblems =
            from p in aux_problem
            join sub in Subject on p.aux_ClassificationID.Id equals sub.Id
            where sub.Title.Contains(searchTerm)
            orderby p.CreatedOn descending
            select new ProblemsViewModel_Base
            {
                aux_CustomID = p.aux_CustomID
                ,
                Id = p.aux_problemId.Value
                ,
                title = p.aux_name
                ,
                CreatedOn = p.CreatedOn.Value
            };

        return subjectProblems;
    }
```

And without Join

```
public IEnumerable<ProblemsViewModel_Base> GetProblemsSearchDetails(string searchTerm){
    var detailsProblems = aux_problem
            .Where(p => p.aux_CustomID.Contains(searchTerm))
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedOn)
         .Select(i => new ProblemsViewModel_Base
            {
                aux_CustomID = i.aux_CustomID
                ,
                Id = i.aux_problemId.Value
                ,
                title = i.aux_name
                ,
                CreatedOn = i.CreatedOn.Value
            });

        return detailsProblems;}
```

After three queries, I'm joining and getting disctinct results with:

```
var joinedResults = detailsResults.Union(requestorResults).Union(classificationResults);
var distinctResults = joinedResults.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(p => p.First())
```

My problem comes when in the results I do the Union with the second query (the one that don't have the join), the results are not ordered, but if I avoid this query, doing the Union of all query with Joins, the results are ordered.

Which could be the problem here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution modifying the comparison like:

```
var distinctResults = joinedResults.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(p => p.First()).OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedOn);
```

I have comment out the OrderBy in all queries because I'm doing it after and I suppose without it, the query will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

By my experience
.Union()
.Distinct()
And some others will undo the ordering 
Try ordering before presenting the results but after all that code

Please Feedback